# Duplicar UserControl en C# WindowsForms

Tags: c#, usercontrol

Tengo un UserControl, pero necesito crear varios de esos, he intentado hacer una instancia, pero me muestra error.
Código: 
`MyControl Control = new MyControl();
El error está En Ambos **MyControl** y es el siguiente:

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'MyControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Si su control esta creado con otro espacio de nombre diferente al que contiene el formulario donde sea crear la instancia al control, debe agregar como referencia la clase o espacio de nombre donde se encuentra su control

Comment: Link, publica el xaml  y el codigo de la clase marcando donde te pasa el error para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el namespace de la clase `MyControl` es distinto al de la clase desde la que la invocas. Deberás añadir el namespace de la clase `MyControl` utilizando `using`.

**Clase MyControl**

```
namespace Proyecto.Clases
{
    public class MyControl
    {
        public MyControl() {}
    }
}
```

**Otra clase**

```
using Proyecto.Clases

namespace Proyecto
{
    public class OtraClase
    {
        public OtraClase()
        {
            MyControl mycontrol = new MyControl();
        }
    }
}
```